# References and Citations not Showing Up

Tags: bibliographies

I need to write a paper in `Times New Roman` so I am using `LuaLaTex` in my `.tex` file with command `% !TEX TS-program = lualatex` and specify the font with `\usepackage{fontspec}` and `\setmainfont{Times New Roman}`. The trouble is I cannot get any citations or references in the paper. Here is an MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{ecta}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\title{The Pathbreaking Paper}
\author{Dr Genius}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{Introduction}
Climate change is an urgent issue that needs an immediate intervention through human actions. 
\nocite{*}
\bibliography{references}
\end{document}
```

My references are saved in a `.bib` file named `references`, saved in the same directory and they look like this:

```
@article{falkner2016paris,
  title={The Paris Agreement and the new logic of international climate      politics},
  author={Falkner, Robert},
  journal={International Affairs},
  volume={92},
  number={5},
  pages={1107--1125},
  year={2016},
  publisher={Oxford University Press}
}
@article{handler1994succession,
  title={Succession in family business: A review of the research},
  author={Handler, Wendy C},
  journal={Family business review},
  volume={7},
  number={2},
  pages={133--157},
  year={1994},
  publisher={Wiley Online Library}
}
```

I tried everything I could think of but could not make the file work. Would appreciate any help. I am using `TeX Live 2019` on `Win 10`.

Comment: In order for the citations to resolve correctly you need to compile your document with LuaLaTeX, BibTeX, LuaLaTeX, LuaLaTeX. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/35864

Comment: The first entry from the `.bib` file is missing the entry type and entry key, but if I ignore it and only take the entry `handler1994succession`, the document compiles fine and I get a bibliography when I run LuaLaTeX, BibTeX, LuaLaTeX, LuaLaTeX.

Comment: @moewe, apologies for missing the entry key and entry type, had made a mistake while writing it and thank you for pointing it out. Is it not the case that after writing `% !TEX TS-program = lualatex`, when I compile my `.tex` file, it gets compiled with `LuaLaTeX`? I ask because i thought that's what writing these at the beginning of the file did.

Comment: `% !TEX TS-program = lualatex` is a magic command to tell certain editors to use LuaLaTeX as the default compiler. Assuming your editor understands this syntax, it probably runs LuaLaTeX for you when you press a "compile" button. In order for the bibliography to appear you additionally need to run BibTeX (and then LuaLaTeX again). This probably needs to be done by selecting BibTeX from some sort of build menu or by using a different keyboard shortcut.